# British Maths Olympiad (BMO) 2004 Round 1 Question 1 alternative approaches?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

The questions states:

> Solve the simultaneous equations (which I respectively label as $
> > \ref{1}, \ref{2}, \ref{3}, \ref{4}$)
>
> $$\begin{align} ab + c + d &= 3 \tag{1} \label{1} \\ bc + d + a &= 5
>  \tag{2} \label{2} \\  cd + a + b &= 2 \tag{3} \label{3} \\  da + b + c
>  &= 6 \tag{4} \label{4} \end{align}$$

where $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers.

I solved this system after quite a while by taking

$eqns$ 1 - 3 = $eqns$ 4 - 2

which yields $a + c = 2$

You can then substitute that in and find the other variables

I also noticed that $(a+1)(b+1) + (a+1)(d+1) + (c+1)(b+1) + (c+1)(d+1) = 20$ but that line didnt really help me.

I'm interested in seeing the other approaches people can take with this system.

Additionally, is there a sufficient enough hint to take another route? Did I miss an easy solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach was to set $A=a-1,B=b-1,C=c-1,D=d-1$ so that we get
\begin{align}
  AB + A + B + C + D &= 0 \\
  BC + A + B + C + D &= 2 \\
  CD + A + B + C + D &= -1 \\
  AD + A + B + C + D &= 3.
\end{align}
Letting $S = A+B+C+D$, we have $ABCD = (-S)(-1-S) = (2-S)(3-S)$, so $S=1$, and therefore 
\begin{align}
   AB &= -1 \\
   BC &= 1 \\
   CD &= -2 \\
   AD &= 2.
\end{align}
This gives us $A = -\frac1B$, $C = \frac1B$, and $D = -\frac2C = -2B$.

From $A+B+C+D=1$, we have $-\frac1B + B + \frac1B - 2B = 1$, or $B = -1$. Then we can solve for $A,C,D$ and finally get $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 7):

**Step 1**: Obtain $a+c=2$.

**Step 2**:

Note that
$$ab+bc+cd+ad=(a+c)(b+d)$$

Adding four equations gives
$$(a+c)(b+d)+2(a+c)+2(b+d)=16$$
$$(a+c)(b+d+2)+2(b+d+2)=20$$
$$(a+c+2)(b+d+2)=20$$

With $a+c=2$, we have $b+d=3$.

**Step 3**:

Further manipulating, 1-2+3-4 gives
$$(a-c)(b+d)=6$$

Thus, $a-c=2$.

Therefore, we have $a=2, c=0$.

**Step 4**: Put $a,c$ into 1,
$$2b+d=3$$
With $b+d=3$, $b=0, d=3$.

Comment: This is a nice factorization. What would the next steps be?

Comment: @Abe See my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way after you get $a+c=2$.

Take equation $2$ subtract equation $1$ to get $(b-1)(c-a)=2$.

Likewise, take equation $3$ subtract equation $4$ to get $(d-1)(c-a) = -4$.

Finally, we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{b-1}{d-1}=\frac{(b-1)(c-a)}{(d-1)(c-a)}= -\frac{1}{2} \ \ \implies \ \ 2b+d =3. 
\end{align}

Next, take equation $1$ plus equation $2$ to get $b(a+c)+(a+c)+2d=8$ which implies $b+d = 3$ since $a+c=2$.

Now, we see that $b=0$ and $d=3$. Using equation $2$, we have that $a=2$ and $c=0$.